# Is $f(x) = x^{x^x}$ monotonic?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, proof-writing, monotone-functions

How can we prove that $f_3 \colon (0, +\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$, $f_3(x) = x^{x^x}$ is monotonic? I tried taking the derivative — didn't work. Can we extend the proof to $f_{2k+1}$ for any $k$ (this function is constructed in a similar way, but $x$ is written $2k-1$ times. For example, $f_5(x) = x^{x^{x^{x^x}}}$)? All ideas are welcome.

Comment: Do you mean "monotonic"? I suppose if you keep on taking powers of $x$ it may eventually become monotonous too...

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1004017/42969

Comment: Or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3279127/42969

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. Is there any way to extend the proof, though?

Comment: Or this: [https://math.stackexchange.com/q/365717/1508](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/365717/1508)

Comment: @TonyK  I will make sure to write it correctly from now on. It’s monoton in German so I just adapted the word I heard in lectures